# Find $a_n$ in terms of $b_n$ given $b_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} a_k$

Tags: generating-functions

Given sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ satifying
$$b_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} a_k$$

I am required to find $a_n$ in terms of $b_n$

---

**My attempt:**

The generating fuction for $b_n$ will be
\begin{align}
B(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} a_k \right)\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose n-k} a_k \right)
\end{align}
This looks like the product of two generating functions $A(x)$ ( for $a_n$ ) and $C(x)$. Hence the given sequence $b_n$ is an convolution of two $a_n$ and some $c_n$.

If now I can find $c_n$, and a closed form for $C(x)$ (which I believe exists), the sequence $a_n$ can be found since $$A(x) = \frac{B(x)}{C(x)}$$

---

**My question:**

I am unable to find the sequence $c_n$. I tried using $c_k = {n \choose k}$ but I am quite sure that it is incorrect.

Comment: Hint: Try to find $a_n$ for small $n$, for example $n=1, 2, 3$. See the pattern that is occurring

Comment: @Jakobian Thanks for the hint. I've obtained that $a_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k {n \choose k} b_{n-k}$. Proving by induction will make sure that the answer is correct. Can the question be solved by generating functions?

Comment: Yes, another way would be to consider exponential generating functions i. e. $B(x) = \sum \frac{b_nx^n}{n!}$ and $A(x) = \sum \frac{a_nx^n}{n!}$, then $B(x) = e^xA(x)$

Comment: @Jakobian You can also use ordinary generating functions, then $xB=(xA)\circ\dfrac{x}{1-x}$, so $xA=(xB)\circ\dfrac{x}{1+x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we are looking for so-called *binomial inverse pairs*. To show the relationship we multiply exponential generating functions (egfs). Let $A(x)=\sum_{n\ge0}a_{n}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ and $B(x)=\sum_{n\ge0}b_{n}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ egfs with $B(x)=A(x)e^x$. Comparing coefficients gives the following

> *Binomial inverse pair*
>   \begin{align*}
> B(x)&=A(x)e^x&A(x)&=B(x)e^{-x}\\
> b_n&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}a_k&a_n&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}b_k
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

The sequence $(b_n)$ is called the *binomial transform* of the sequence $(a_n)$, so $(a_n)$ is the *inverse binomial transform* of $(b_n)$. We can take ordinary generating functions of both sides, say, $A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$, $B(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nx^n$, then
$$
\begin{split}
B(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}a_kx^n=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\binom{n}{k}a_kx^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k\left(\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\binom{n}{k}x^n\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k\frac{x^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}}\\
&=\frac{1}{1-x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^k=\frac{1}{1-x}A\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right),
\end{split}
$$
or equivalently,
$$
xB(x)=\frac{x}{1-x}A\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)=(xA(x))\circ\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)
$$
Note that the inverse function of $\frac{x}{1-x}$ is $\frac{x}{1+x}$, so
$$
xA(x)=(xB(x))\circ\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)=\frac{x}{1+x}B\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right),
$$
i.e.
$$
\begin{split}
A(x)&=\frac{1}{1+x}B\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{1-x}B\left(-\frac{x}{1-x}\right)\right)\circ(-x)\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^kb_k\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^k\right)\circ(-x)\\
&=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^kb_kx^n\right)\circ(-x)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^kb_k(-x)^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^kb_k(-1)^nx^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}b_kx^n,
\end{split}
$$
so
$$
a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}b_k.
$$